# What happens as the 2 same bar magnets are placed in the same plane with same direction?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

[image]

I want to observe how the force(s) act(s) between the 2 magnets as the 2 same bar magnets are placed in same plane with same direction like above diagram.

$\pm m~$ represents the strengths of each pole.

The description states "**from the symmetry , the only component(s) which remain(s) are vertical against the line of the magnet.**"

How the symmetry is taken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the distance between magnetic poles is large relative to the diameter of the poles, then their interactions are similar to those of electric charges. In your situation the repulsion forces between like poles will exceed the attractions between the opposite poles. In the absence of other forces, the two magnets will separate.